# Where is the mic located on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, microphone, speaker

I have downloaded an app for calculating distance of the phone to the wall It is known as [sonar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dicon.sonar.ad&referrer=utm_source%3Dappbrain%26utm_medium%3Dappbrain_web%26utm_campaign%3Dappbrain_web). I want to test this app. So, I covered the `speakers` [image]

of the phone which could be could found on the back side at the bottom of the phone.On doing so the app showed noticeable change in the distance calculated. However, I could not find the mic's exact location. I want to cover up the `mic`, and would like to observe any noticeable distance change. Then are couple of holes on the periphery of the phone, however, on closing each of them I could not find any noticeable. Can anybody show me in picture when can I exactly find the location of the mic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the mic on the Samsung Galaxy S2
[image: Actual Mic]

And this is another mic on the top. In the user guide it says that it is a "mouthpiece" I presume by that they mean a microphone that is only active when you use the speakerphone feature or record videos or when the user is on a video call.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, even after blocking both of these holes, I could still record my voice using the sound recorder app.